# How can I be paid as founder of a LLC?

Tags: usa, llc

A group of friends are going to create a non-resident LLC in the USA. My question is how can we be paid as company founders?
Would be possible to be registered as self-employed in our respective countries and send invoices to our own company? Will that be fine?

Comment: The point with an LCC is to reduce liability and come out on top in terms of taxes that are usually higher for personal taxes. You are most likely required to be paid by accepting a salary and once you have enough money to pay salary the remainder that is not used for operation can be paid out as a yearly dividend. However, It's best to ask a tax accountant in your country. Laws vary country to country and it depends on what you're doing. Where I'm from companies are obligated to pay a salary to their owners if they're doing work for the company. Owners/investors then get dividend.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

> [F]oreign owners may act as consultants to the LLC under a written
>   Consultant’s agreement completing all consulting work within their
>   home country and billing the LLC in the United States for this
>   service. By doing so, it may be possible to eliminate profits thus
>   avoiding some taxation, as well as U.S. situs (located) earnings,
>   which would be subject to the U.S. tax regime, even for non-residents.
>
> [EPGD Business Law](https://www.epgdlaw.com/llc-foreign-owners/)

But read the entire article I linked to.